# Organizing and filtering a difficult and random associative/multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I have an array which I have merged using certain identifiers in a database to create a larger array with all of the information I need. I now need to filter or sort this information in a way which can allow me to easily organize and then sum some of the information I have gathered.

This array is really messy and I simply have never had to do such a process for 'cleaning' an array, but the database is so unorganized in my limited experiences knew no easier method or PHP functions to fix this. I also do not know certain terminology to search for easier solutions to this problem, so this may be solved elsewhere at least in part but I didn't know what to search for.

My goals are to:

1. Rename the primary index from the hashes that are present now to simply 0,1,2...
2. Remove ALL arrays which do not have the "roleID" key in them
3. Sum all of the 'hours' totals in the remaining arrays and then add a new key named "totalHours" which will have the value of the summed hours total per that particular array.

I've tried iterating through arrays and using nested for loops, but the numbering in these arrays make it such that I need to rename them before I can use these methods properly.

The reason that the keys in the 'hours' are so awkward is due to the way that I retrieve the hours from the database. I can't search based off the user.

```
Array
(
    [5b6468a500277c71b98405b1f140991c] => Array
        (
            [roleID] => 5b6468a500277c71b98405b1f140991c
            [ID] => 5b6468a500277c71b98405b1f140991c
            [name] => CED
            [rateValue] => 10
            [hours] => Array
                (
                    [23] => 0.25
                    [36] => 0.5
                    [38] => 0.5
                    [43] => 0.5
                    [53] => 0.5
                    [57] => 1
                    [60] => 1
                    [61] => 1
                    [62] => 1
                    [63] => 1
                    [64] => 1
                    [66] => 1
                    [71] => 2
                    [73] => 2.5
                    [79] => 7.5
                )

        )

    [5b6468a500277c74f6b2c065436b7d17] => Array
        (
            [roleID] => 5b6468a500277c74f6b2c065436b7d17
            [ID] => 5b6468a500277c74f6b2c065436b7d17
            [name] => ADR
            [rateValue] => 100
            [hours] => Array
                (
                    [4] => 0.25
                    [76] => 3
                )

        )

    [5b6468a500277c80b63cfcc15c2dacf2] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 5b6468a500277c80b63cfcc15c2dacf2
            [name] => DST
            [rateValue] => 195
        )
```

My goal in the first iteration would be to get the three above arrays to look like so:

```
Array
(
// changed from hash to '0'
    [0] => Array
        (
            [roleID] => 5b6468a500277c71b98405b1f140991c
            [ID] => 5b6468a500277c71b98405b1f140991c
            [name] => CED
            [rateValue] => 10
            [hours] => Array
                (
                    [23] => 0.25
                    [36] => 0.5
                    [38] => 0.5
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [roleID] => 5b6468a500277c74f6b2c065436b7d17
            [ID] => 5b6468a500277c74f6b2c065436b7d17
            [name] => ADR
            [rateValue] => 100
            [hours] => Array
                (
                    [4] => 0.25
                    [76] => 3
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 5b6468a500277c80b63cfcc15c2dacf2
            [name] => DST
            [rateValue] => 195
        )
```

Then in the second to look like so (if necessary)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [roleID] => 5b6468a500277c71b98405b1f140991c
            [ID] => 5b6468a500277c71b98405b1f140991c
            [name] => CED
            [rateValue] => 10
// hours array keys changed for simpler addition (if you think this is necessary)

            [hours] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0.25
                    [1] => 0.5
                    [2] => 0.5
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [roleID] => 5b6468a500277c74f6b2c065436b7d17
            [ID] => 5b6468a500277c74f6b2c065436b7d17
            [name] => ADR
            [rateValue] => 100
            [hours] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0.25
                    [1] => 3
                )

// index 2 in step 1 deleted because it does not have the roleID key/value

        )
```

Then in the third to look like so:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [roleID] => 5b6468a500277c71b98405b1f140991c
            [ID] => 5b6468a500277c71b98405b1f140991c
            [name] => CED
            [rateValue] => 10
            [hours] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0.25
                    [1] => 0.5
                    [2] => 0.5
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [roleID] => 5b6468a500277c74f6b2c065436b7d17
            [ID] => 5b6468a500277c74f6b2c065436b7d17
            [name] => ADR
            [rateValue] => 100
            [hours] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0.25
                    [1] => 3
                )

//third element deleted because it does not have the roleID key/value

        )
```

Then finally:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [roleID] => 5b6468a500277c71b98405b1f140991c
            [ID] => 5b6468a500277c71b98405b1f140991c
            [name] => CED
            [rateValue] => 10
            [hours] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0.25
                    [1] => 0.5
                    [2] => 0.5
                )
            [totalHours] => 1.25

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [roleID] => 5b6468a500277c74f6b2c065436b7d17
            [ID] => 5b6468a500277c74f6b2c065436b7d17
            [name] => ADR
            [rateValue] => 100
            [hours] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0.25
                    [1] => 3
                )
            [totalHours] => 3.25


        )
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Can be done with `array_values` ([documentation](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)) but also just add element to array will use int keys
2. Simple foreach with `isset` ([documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)) check
3. `array_sum` to the rescue ([documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php))

Consider the following simple pseudo code:

```
foreach($array as $e) {
    if (isset["roleID"]) {
        $e["totalHours"] = array_sum($e["hours"]);
        unset($e["hours"]); // only if you don't want it anymore 
        $res[] = $e;
    }
}
```

And that it

Comment: Hey, well I got the array_values to reorganize the array, that was easy enough... then I can output the summed totals of the array_sum[$e['hours'] but when I try to add another key/value of totalHours to the array while inside of the foreach, the value does not get set.   foreach($final_array as $array){
   if(isset($array['roleID']))
   {
    if(isset($array['hours']))
    {
     $array['totalHours'] = array_sum($array['hours']);
    }
   }

Comment: sorry i think im figuring this out, should have thought a little more.  i am adding all of these changes to a new array, not the old array i am iterating through.

Comment: @User14289 Correct. I used a new array as you wanted to filter some of the data. If this post helped you - you may mark it as accepted (the grey "v" mark at the left of the post) so other may use it